.NET Maui Hybrid App with MudBlazor not opening MudDialog (inline)
I have a MAUI Project targeting Android and Windows. I Use MudBlazor components. In this case I have a simple MudDialog defined inline like this:
<MudDialog @bind-IsVisible="@Item.IsEditMode" Options="dialogOptions">
    <TitleContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">
            <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Edit" Class="mr-3" /> Edit Item
        </MudText>
    </TitleContent>

    <DialogContent>
        <MudStack Row="true" AlignItems="AlignItems.Baseline" Class="stack-content">
            <MudTextField T="double" Class="no-grow"
                          ReadOnly="@(!Item.IsEditMode)"
                          DisableUnderLine="true"
                          Format="@StringFormatQuantityType(Item.ShopItemQuantityType)"
                          Variant="Variant.Text" @bind-Value="@Item.Quantity">
            </MudTextField>

            <MudSelect T="ShopItemQuantityType" @bind-Value="Item.ShopItemQuantityType" MaxHeight="200" Dense="true" ReadOnly="@(!Item.IsEditMode)">
                @foreach (ShopItemQuantityType enu in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ShopItemQuantityType)))
                {
                    <MudSelectItem Value="@enu">@enu</MudSelectItem>
                }
            </MudSelect>

            <MudTextField T="string" Class=""
                          ReadOnly="@(!Item.IsEditMode)"
                          DisableUnderLine="true"
                          Variant="Variant.Text" @bind-Value="@Item.Name">
            </MudTextField>

        </MudStack>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="@(() => Item.IsEditMode = false)" Class="px-10">Close</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>

</MudDialog>

here my CSS, where i define following BackgroundClass:
 .dialog-background-blur {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

I do have following C#:
    public partial class ShopItemComponent : ComponentBase
    {
        private DialogOptions dialogOptions = new() { FullWidth = true, ClassBackground = "dialog-background-blur", };

        [Parameter] public ShopItem Item { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public EventCallback<ShopItem> OnItemUpdated { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public bool IsTouchDevice { get; set; }

        [...]
    }

My problem is, when i deploy to my physical Android with API33 (Android Version 13), what my project is made for, i can not open the dialog. I do not see any line in console of VS22 nor in Chrome/inspect window referring to any problem. But on the other side, it works when deploying to windows target and it works on Android, when i touch via inspect window on the remote device with no problem! So the code seems to work generally but there seems to be a problem when handle on physical device.
Also nor on physical device nor on remote device via chroime-inspect my css class is added!
Any hint for me?
Thank you guys!

I had the same issue. Never received an answer. Seems no one uses Maui. its a dead platform. Microsoft would be smart to scrap Maui and Xaml and move to straight Blazor. A mobile version of Blazor just makes too much sense but Microsoft gonna Microsoft.
So for me I scrapped everything maui and imported Mudblazor and all of its components. No shared projects or Razor Component Libraries and built a Maui app based on 100% Mudblazor and Syncfusion Blazor. it works no complaints
Sorry for the rant. I saw the issue here but It doesnt work still https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/22343

I believe dialogs in MudBlazor might be implemented using popovers, which could make your issue related to one I recently encountered. After migrating MudBlazor to the latest version (7.4.0 as of this writing), I noticed that MudSelect was no longer opening the popover to display the options.
The solution was to add <MudPopoverProvider /> in the layout file.
Here’s a brief step-by-step on how I fixed it:

Locate your layout file (e.g., MainLayout.razor).

Add <MudPopoverProvider /> inside the layout file. Here’s an example:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<MudThemeProvider Theme="@_theme"/>
<MudDialogProvider/>
<MudSnackbarProvider/>
<MudPopoverProvider/> // @* <-- Add this *@



After making this addition, the Popover component should start working as expected.
